# java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Collection doesn't contain element at index 4

Tags: java

```
if (mWeakHashMap.size() > idx) {
        mUploadThreads.remove(mUploadThreads.elementAt(idx))
}
```

Why did the code above thrown an `IndexOutOfBoundsException`?

Any one can help me?

Comment: You're checking `mWeakHashMap.size` and removing from `mUploadThreads` - which doesn't make sense...

Comment: I am so sorry, I did not explain the code above clearly: mWeakHashMap is the a reference to mUploadThread.

Comment: Have you verified that they point to the same data?

Comment: @Jackson What is the type of "mUploadThreads"?

Answer (score 0):

I think it is because you are removing an element from a collection without checking its size first. What you should check instead is:

```
if(mUploadThreads.size() > idx)
```

Answer (score 0):

The `HashMap` has a `constainsKey` and a `remove` method that you can use to effectively check if a `key` is in the map before attempting to remove it.

Below is a basic example where I add two elements to a HashMap and then remove one of the elements.

```
import java.util.HashMap;

public class HashMapExample {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
        map.put("Key1", "Value1");
        map.put("Key2", "Value2");

        System.out.println(String.format("Map size: %d", map.size()));

        if (map.containsKey("Key2")) {
            map.remove("Key2");
        }

        System.out.println(String.format("Map size: %d", map.size()));
    }
}

/* Output
Map size: 2
Map size: 1
*/
```

So in your example, if `mWeakHashMap` is a reference to `mUploadThread`, I would change the way you're checking and removing the element to something more like this:

```
if (mWeakHashMap.constainsKey("<Your_Key>")) {
        mUploadThreads.remove("<Your_Key>");
}
```

Hope this helps.